Zeebe Brokers and Gateway communication on VM's and OpenShift architecture
My configuration is that Zeebe brokers are on VM’s and the Gateway and Operate are in the OpenShift k8s cluster.
I need to establish connection between my brokers and Gateway. Is it possible to do this with the OpenShift’s routes? And if yes, can you tell me, please, how?
I've seen, that Gateway can process requests from the clients via Routes in OpenShift (with HTTP/2). But there is no imformation about configuring Gateway to accept broker's messages throùgh the Route
